# Duda con el patron Value Object clases relaccionadas en el modelo de datos

Tags: patrones-de-diseño

Por ejemplo si tenemos el modelo de datos y el modelo relacional en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creamos nuestras clases value object:

```
class PersonaVO {
    constructor(dni,nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    setDni(dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }
    getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }
    setNombre(nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }
}
module.exports = PersonaVO;


class EmpleadoVO {
    constructor(idEmpleado,nombreEmpresa) {
        this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
        this.nombreEmpresa = nombreEmpresa;
    }

    setIdEmpleado(idEmpleado) {
        this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
    }
    getIdEmpleado() {
        return this.idEmpleado;
    }
    setNombreEmpresa(nombreEmpresa) {
        this.nombreEmpresa = nombreEmpresa;
    }
    getNombreEmpresa() {
        return this.nombreEmpresa;
    }
}
module.exports = EmpleadoVO;
```

Sabemos que un empleado es una persona que ademas de tener la idEmpleado y nombre de la empresa tambien tiene el nombre y el dni, donde el dni coincide con el idEmpleado.
Cuando vamos a la capa de vista para rellenar los campos de un formulario, que objeto usamos? Los dos value object independientes y los pasamos al controlador para insertar y a la capa de persistencia y despues las juntamos mediante una sentencia sql para inscribir en la base de datos, o creamos un value object de empleado que sea una clase derivada de persona y despues insertamos en la base de datos mediante el patron data access object.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el patrón DTO (Data Transfer Object) que contenga toda la información que necesitas pasar al controlador.
Una vez en el controlador, creas los objetos, para luego pasar a la capa de dao o service, según la arquitectura que estás usando.